# Why are jobs reported differently when invoked from PROMPT_COMMAND function?

Tags: bash

I have a function which I add to the `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check git status and count background jobs (among other things). This is a MWE:

```sh
mainprompt() {
    if git status -s &>/dev/null; then
        echo "You are in a git repo"
    fi
    local jobct=0
    local line
    while read -r line; do
        echo "<$line>"
        let jobct++
    done < <(jobs)
    echo "You have $jobct background job(s)"
}
```

When I call this function from a standalone script, it works as expected.

```sh
mainprompt
sleep 3s &
mainprompt
```

produces:

```
You have 0 background job(s)
<[1]+  Running                 sleep 3s &>
You have 1 background job(s)
```

But when I use this function as my `PROMPT_COMMAND`, the `jobs` builtin is reporting the `git status` call so that I always have, at minimum, 1 background job reported.

```sh
export PROMPT_COMMAND="mainprompt"
```

```
<[1]   Exit 128                git status -s &> /dev/null>
You have 1 background job(s)
bash-5.1$ :
<[1]   Exit 128                git status -s &> /dev/null>
You have 1 background job(s)
bash-5.1$ sleep 3s &
<[1]+  Running                 sleep 3s &>
<[2]   Exit 128                git status -s &> /dev/null>
You have 2 background job(s)
bash-5.1$
```

Why does `git status` show up as a background job when invoked from the `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

I can easily move the job counting to the beginning of this function, but I am curious for the reason behind the unexpected (at least to me) behavior.

edit: I’m aware that `\j` expands to the background job count in `PS1` but I can’t use it since this prompt needs to know the exact character length of the text to do right justification.